# how can I debug a node app that is started via the command line (cli) like forever or supervisor?

Tags: node.js, debugging

I'm familiar with debugging my own node apps (usually with node-inspector). Today I'd like to debug someone else's program. I'm trying to track down an issue with [`supervisor`](https://github.com/petruisfan/node-supervisor). So naturally I just add a `--debug` (or `debug-brk`) to the command call, but it passes that to the code that it is supervising.

I've tried adding `debugger` lines to the js file for supervisor but that didn't work (probably because no debugger was attached at that time). There's a bit of a race here -- I need to start the debugger and attach it to the supervisor process after it starts but before it processes its arguments from the command line.

What I really want to do here is stop `supervisor` and debug it before it processes its command line arguments. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem while developing my [hexo](https://hexo.io/) blog.  The documentation isn't all that complete yet so I find myself needing to reverse engineer at times.

The basic idea is that in Node.js even your cli apps are simply normal node apps that you are exposing to the OS command line interface. On Unix systems you are using this line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

To allow the environment to execute the script.

Many cli based node apps try to insist that you install them globally with the -g option.

```
npm install -g node-inspector
```

I personally prefer to have as much control of my development environment as I can get, so I prefer to break some conventions and check my node_modules in to source control along with installing everything I can locally by dropping the -g.

```
npm install node-inspector
```

Now you don't have to do this in order to make this work, I'm just describing this setup because it relates to your question.  When I run node-inspector I can't simply use:

```
node-inspector
```

Instead I must explicitly invoke it from within my project.  I do this by executing the symlink in my node_modules/.bin folder:

```
node_modules/.bin/node-inspector
```

Now I'm running node-inspector just like you.

Next all I need to do is start the cli process in debug and optionally pass params to it:

```
node --debug-brk node_modules/.bin/hexo generate
```

Note I am explicitly calling the symlink here and not simply:

```
node --debug-brk hexo generate
```

If I tried the line above I would get an error: "Error: Cannot find module".

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this, with a `debugger;` in `./node_modules/hexo/lib/hexo/index.js:Hexo()`, but all I get is "Debugger listening on port 5858" on stdout, then hangs. Doesn't get to an interactive debugger, doesn't generate.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you...  I have only tried the commands I detailed above in the terminal.  If you are using an IDE with a built in debugger or something else I haven't tried that... I was also starting the execution just as the regular command would only more explicit about the path to .bin location.

Comment: Not using an IDE. I'm trying to figure out a bug in a hexo plugin, so my strategy is to put a `debugger;` in the file mentioned above. When I run `/usr/local/bin/node --debug-brk node_modules/.bin/hexo generate`, it just hangs, with or without the `debugger;` in there. Any idea why?

Comment: last time I did this, which was some time ago now, It would sometimes hang for a good few minutes before actually connecting to the debugger.  How long did you wait before declaring it hung?  All else fails you could resort to caveman debugging with prints, atleast until you figure out the issue.  I know that isn't very helpful, but I do recall it being kinda hit and miss.

Comment: Nope. I gave up on Hexo/other node static site generators and just went with Jekyll.

Comment: I could debug hexo by installing `hexo-cli` as a dev dependency instead of global, then adding a script to `package.json` called debug, with this command: `node --inspect=4300 ./node_modules/hexo-cli/bin/hexo server`. Then I can connect with a debugger to port 4300.